# Force safari doubletap to zoom into a specific div

Tags: javascript, ios, safari, zooming

Is there a way to make (or trick) Mobile Safari to zoom into a specific div when double taping?

I have a lot of divs that are part of my layout, but after a lot of tries I still can not understand how Safari doubletap algorithm works. It seems to prefer to zoom into HTML elements that are children instead of their parents.

I tried to create an empty div with a high z-index and no background (so it becomes transparent) that covers the area that I want safari to zoom-in when the user double taps that area, but it doesn't work.

Comment: I just want to add that I still haven't found a way to do this, I believe it's not possible